# How to get view hierarchy with detail of a view controller from any other view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a **UIViewController** at run time i add views into that view controller Programmatically.Now i want to print view hierarchy of that view controller from any other view controller.I want to know which exact view is added.For example if i have added view like this

```
UIView *main_view=[UiView alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,34,80)];
```

Then i want it to print **exact name** of that view.It only prints the address of that view & frame details.Please suggest me how can i do it ?

Comment: What name? A view doesn't have a name.

Comment: When you want an 'exact name' you have to 'exactly' specify what you mean by that

Comment: like i made a an instance of UIView main_view then it should print that instancce name main_view

Comment: main_view is pointer for current allocated memory so you can't get that thing

Comment: why you need that name , you can set tag to your view and from hierarchy get that view from tag and compare if (self.main_view == foundView)

Comment: Yes, a little more context on what you're trying to do would be helpful. If we understand the broader objective, we might be able to offer better ways to address that.

Comment: I guess settings is the only way left

Comment: How can i print a view with tag.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what variables are.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recursively iterate the sub views.

```
- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return; // COUNT CHECK LINE

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        // Do what you want to do with the subview
        NSLog(@"%@", subview);

        // List the subviews of subview
        [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can set unique tag to each subview and then when you fetch view the compare view tag and if it match with the particule tag, that will be the view for which you are looking for.


UIView *main_view=[UiView alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,34,80)];
main_view.tag = 1000;
[self.view addSubView:main_view];



// fetch view
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:1000];
if ( view.tag == 1000 ){
    NSLog("This is view - main_view");
}
```